Material-UI slider with multiple useState is duplicated on click
I'm trying to create a font size and font weight previewer using Material-Ui sliders and useState, but when I click the first slider after clicking the second, the first slider is duplicated.

Here is my code:
import React from "react";
import { withStyles, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Slider from "@material-ui/core/Slider";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: 300 + theme.spacing(3) * 2
  },
  margin: {
    height: theme.spacing(3)
  }
}));

const iOSBoxShadow =
  "0 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),0 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.13),0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.02)";

const marks = [
  {
    value: 0
  },
  {
    value: 25
  },
  {
    value: 50
  },
  {
    value: 75
  },
  {
    value: 100
  }
];

const IOSSlider = withStyles({
  root: {
    color: "#3880ff",
    height: 2,
    padding: "15px 0"
  },
  thumb: {
    height: 28,
    width: 28,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    boxShadow: iOSBoxShadow,
    marginTop: -14,
    marginLeft: -14,
    "&:focus, &:hover, &$active": {
      boxShadow:
        "0 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),0 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3),0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.02)",
      // Reset on touch devices, it doesn't add specificity
      "@media (hover: none)": {
        boxShadow: iOSBoxShadow
      }
    }
  },
  active: {},
  valueLabel: {
    left: "calc(-50% + 12px)",
    top: -22,
    "& *": {
      background: "transparent",
      color: "#000"
    }
  },
  track: {
    height: 2
  },
  rail: {
    height: 2,
    opacity: 0.5,
    backgroundColor: "#bfbfbf"
  },
  mark: {
    backgroundColor: "#bfbfbf",
    height: 8,
    width: 1,
    marginTop: -3
  },
  markActive: {
    opacity: 1,
    backgroundColor: "currentColor"
  }
})(Slider);

export default function CustomizedSlider() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [userFontSize, setUserFontSize] = React.useState("1rem");
  const [userFontWeight, setUserFontWeight] = React.useState("300");
  const [sliderSizeTracker, setSliderSizeTracker] = React.useState(0);
  const [sliderWeightTracker, setSliderWeightTracker] = React.useState(999);


  const handleSizeChange = (e, newSizeValue) => {
    switch (newSizeValue) {
      case 0: {
        setUserFontSize("1rem");
        setSliderSizeTracker(0);
        break;
      }
      case 25: {
        setUserFontSize("1.19rem");
        setSliderSizeTracker(25);
        break;
      }
      case 50: {
        setUserFontSize("1.37rem");
        setSliderSizeTracker(50);
        break;
      }
      case 75: {
        setUserFontSize("1.55rem");
        setSliderSizeTracker(75);
        break;
      }
      case 100: {
        setUserFontSize("1.75rem");
        setSliderSizeTracker(100);
        break;
      }
      default: {
        break;
      }
    }
  };

  const handleWeightChange = (e, newWeightValue) => {
    switch (newWeightValue) {
      case 0: {
        setUserFontWeight("300");
        setSliderWeightTracker(0);
        break;
      }
      case 25: {
        setUserFontWeight("400");
        setSliderWeightTracker(25);
        break;
      }
      case 50: {
        setUserFontWeight("500");
        setSliderWeightTracker(50);
        break;
      }
      case 75: {
        setUserFontWeight("700");
        setSliderWeightTracker(75);
        break;
      }
      case 100: {
        setUserFontWeight("900");
        setSliderWeightTracker(100);
        break;
      }
      default: {
        break;
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <Container maxWidth="sm" style={{ marginTop: "2em" }}>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Typography gutterBottom>Font Size Slider</Typography>
        <IOSSlider
          aria-label="Font Size Slider"
          key={sliderSizeTracker}
          defaultValue={sliderSizeTracker}
          marks={marks}
          step={25}
          onChangeCommitted={handleSizeChange}
          valueLabelDisplay="off"
        />
        <Typography gutterBottom>Font Weight Slider</Typography>
        <IOSSlider
          aria-label="Font Weight Slider"
          key={sliderWeightTracker}
          defaultValue={sliderWeightTracker}
          marks={marks}
          step={25}
          onChangeCommitted={handleWeightChange}
          valueLabelDisplay="off"
        />
        <div className={classes.margin} />
        <TextField
          sx={{ border: 'none', "& fieldset": { border: 'none' }, }}
          margin="normal"
          required
          fullWidth
          inputProps={{ style: { fontSize: `${userFontSize}`, fontWeight: `${userFontWeight}` } }}
          defaultValue="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
          multiline
          rows={2}
        />
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
}


codesandbox
I think it has something to do with the way I'm using useState, but the functionality itself seems to work.

Your sandbox doesn't appear to reproduce the issue as you describe. Do you have more accurate/complete reproduction steps?

Oh wait, it finally did, but I had to click between the two sliders a few times. And the more you keep clicking/interacting with the "first" slider, it eventually adds more. I think this is an issue with Material-UI. Your code is only rendering the two IOSSlider components, but for some reason the DOM is receiving duplicate elements.

Removing the key props on the IOSSlider components appears to fix the issue in your sandbox.
<IOSSlider
  aria-label="Font Size Slider"
  // key={sliderSizeTracker} // <-- remove this
  defaultValue={sliderSizeTracker}
  marks={marks}
  step={25}
  onChangeCommitted={handleSizeChange}
  valueLabelDisplay="off"
/>

<IOSSlider
  aria-label="Font Weight Slider"
  // key={sliderWeightTracker} // <-- remove this
  defaultValue={sliderWeightTracker}
  marks={marks}
  step={25}
  onChangeCommitted={handleWeightChange}
  valueLabelDisplay="off"
/>

The other issue in your sandbox is that you are using React 18 but using the pre-React 18 ReactDOM pattern to render your app. It should be updated to the following:
index.js
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import Demo from "./demo";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(<Demo />);


Thanks! I have the demo in React, but I've set this up in NextJS. Removing the key seems to have fixed this.

@mettamyron Sure thing, nothing obvious (to me) was an issue, so started looking at dependency versions and working my way down the ReactTree from the root. I suppose the real question now is why would adding a React key there like that cause any sort of duplicate component rendering issue. ‍♂️ I've never seen anything like that before. Glad this solution is sufficient for you. Cheers!
